# swift , pass data from class to viewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, socket.io

I have data get from socket

and I stored it in object
I use `NSNotificationCenter`. Is there  another way to pass this data from socket class to view Controller directly ??

Comment: i assume you are using socket-io client for ios. If you are receiving the response and setting the data to an object in the response block, isn't it straight forward to publish the data to all listeners? can you elaborate on what exactly you have done and what you are looking for?

Comment: i want to pass when recived from socket to view controller  directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `ResponseDelegate` protocol

```
protocol ResponseDelegate {
    func didReceiveResponse(data:AnyObject?)
}
```

Have a reference to your delegate in your socket class

```
class SocketClass {
    var responseDelegate:ResponseDelegate //This should be implemented and referred to your ViewController

    func getCurrentAmount() {
        [socket on:@"currentAmount" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
           responseDelegate.didReceiveResponse(data)
        }
    }
 }
```

In your `ViewController`

```
//Set your delegate here
socketClassObject.responseDelegate = self

func didReceiveResponse(data:AnyObject) {
       println("Recieved data:\(data)")
}
```

Using **NSNotificationsCentre**

In your ViewController

```
//Subscribe/Listen for the events
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "didReceiveResponse:", name:"CurrentAmountNotification", object: nil)

func didReceiveResponse(notification: NSNotification) {
       println("Recieved data:\(notification.userInfo)")
}
```

In your SocketClass

```
  class SocketClass {

    func getCurrentAmount() {
        [socket on:@"currentAmount" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
           NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("CurrentAmountNotification", object: nil, userInfo:data)
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: i use NSNotificationsCenter 
what's different between your Solution and NSNotificationsCenter

Comment: Updated my answer to do it NSNotifications way, its more of a design decision, delegates are mostly used in a 1:1 relationship and NSNotifications for 1:N, it depends on what you are looking for. If multiple classes are consuming the SocketClass then go for NSNotifications.

Answer (score 3):

You have to give the segue an identifier in the storyboard.(say **vs_segue**)

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){....}
```

Is called for all segues being called form your current UIViewController. So the identifier is to differentiate the different segues

Then use this code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "vs_segue" {
    var nextScene =  segue.destinationViewController as! VehicleDetailsTableViewController

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        nextScene.currentObjectInNextScreen = selectedObjectWhichYouHave
  }
}
```

Place a break point after var nextScene and see if it is being triggered on clicking/changing ViewController. If it isn't then the identifier name u provided in the storyboard must be different then the one given here.

Thanks

Happy Coding.

Comment: if i'm in some view controller and recive data from socket io
i want to pass this data to view controller